# neo4j/cypher: Modelling football managers hired/fired dates

Tags: neo4j, cypher

I'm trying to model when British football managers were hired and fired by their clubs and came up with the following model:

```
Tenure-[:HIRED_ON]-date1
Tenure-[:FIRED_ON]-date2
Tenure-[:MANAGER]-manager
Tenure-[:TEAM]-team`
```

I've got a dummy data set here -> http://console.neo4j.org/?id=nmeaef

The data modelling style is taken from -> http://docs.neo4j.org/chunked/snapshot/cypher-cookbook-path-tree.html#cookbook-return-partly-shared-path-ranges

What I'd like to do is find who the manager for a team was on a certain date and if they didn't have a manager then it should indicate that.

So on the 2nd January in my data set both clubs have a manager as neither has been fired yet and this query works ok:

```
START team = node:node_auto_index('name:"Chelsea" name:"Manchester United"'), 
      startDate = node:node_auto_index(name="2nd") 
MATCH startDate<-[:NEXT*0..]-day 
WITH team, startDate, COLLECT(day) AS dates 
MATCH startDate<-[:NEXT*0..]-day<-[hire:HIRED_ON]-tenure-[:MANAGER]->manager, 
      tenure-[:TEAM]->team, tenure-[?:FIRED_ON]-dateFired 
WHERE dateFired IS NULL OR NOT dateFired IN dates 
RETURN team.name, manager.name, tenure, hire.date, dateFired
```

But on the 5th January it doesn't work as I want because by that date the Chelsea manager has been fired so I want to indicate that they don't have a manager but instead what happens is I just don't get a row for Chelsea because I've filtered it out with the WHERE clause.

But without the WHERE clause it suggested Mourinho is manager which isn't right either since he was fired on the 3rd January.

Any ideas on how I can do what I want? Should I be modelling it differently to do that?

Cheers, Mark

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's the 2.0 way, with case/when:

```
START team = node:node_auto_index('name:"Chelsea" name:"Manchester United"'), startDate = node:node_auto_index(name="5th") 
MATCH startDate<-[:NEXT*0..]-day 
WITH team, startDate, COLLECT(day) AS dates 
MATCH startDate<-[:NEXT*0..]-day<-[hire:HIRED_ON]-tenure-[:MANAGER]->manager, tenure-[:TEAM]->team, tenure-[?:FIRED_ON]-dateFired 
RETURN team.name, 
  CASE WHEN dateFired is null THEN manager.name ELSE null END as managerName, 
  CASE WHEN dateFired is null THEN tenure ELSE null END as tenure, 
  CASE WHEN dateFired is null THEN hire.date ELSE null END as hireDate
```

There's probably a way to do it using WITH also, but this is easy enough.

Answer (score 1):

Good idea Mr Freeman, maybe now is the time to port the graph to use 2.0 then!

I created a version on here -> http://console-test.neo4j.org/?id=z3i6ns

Had to change the query slightly to do what I want:

```
START team = node:node_auto_index('name:"Chelsea" name:"Manchester United"'), 
      startDate = node:node_auto_index(name="2nd") 
MATCH startDate<-[:NEXT*0..]-day 
WITH team, startDate, COLLECT(day) AS dates 
MATCH startDate<-[:NEXT*0..]-day<-[hire:HIRED_ON]-tenure-[:MANAGER]->manager, 
      dateFired<-[?:FIRED_ON]-tenure-[:TEAM]->team
RETURN team.name,    
   CASE WHEN dateFired is null THEN manager.name 
        WHEN dateFired IN dates THEN null 
        ELSE manager.name END as managerName,    
   CASE WHEN dateFired is null THEN tenure 
        WHEN dateFired IN dates THEN null 
        ELSE tenure END as tenure,    
   CASE WHEN dateFired is null THEN hire.date 
        WHEN dateFired IN dates THEN null 
        ELSE hire.date END as hireDate
```

Seems to take quite a while to execute the queries - I'm going to try it out on a real data set - http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_Premier_League_managers - so it'll be interesting to see what the query speed is like there.

Comment: It might perform better to have a relationship from the manager to the team, and two properties for the two dates (considering there probably aren't too many managers per team). Optional relationships are slow to match. Something to try maybe.